# Iteration input and update on dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

Keys of dictionay ***y***

I have dictionary **x**

```
x = {1 :'a', 2 :'b', 3 :'c', 4 :'d', 5 :'e'}
```

The program displays these as choices.  Next, the user selects one to update, and then enters a value.  The program is supposed to add this value to the running total in another dictionary, **y**.

of dictionary x), and then

> values

of ***x*** will input to dictionary ***y*** as **keys**

Example :

```
$python mysc.py
1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
choose number to input case : **1**
you choose 'a'  #now i have a as keys of dictionary *y*
input number : **5**
y = { 'a' : 5 }

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
choose number to input case : **1**
you choose 'a'  #now i have a as keys of dictionary *y*
input number : **6**
y = { 'a' : 11 } #values of 'a' change to 11(5+6)

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
choose number to input case : **5**
you choose 'e'  #now we add a new keys of dictionary *y*
input number : **6**
y = { 'a' : 11, 'e' : 5  }
```

Code:

```
y = {}
while True:
    x = {1 :'a', 2 :'b', 3 :'c', 4 :'d', 5 :'e'}
    n = input('choose number to input keys : ')
    nn = x[n]
    print 'your choose is ',x[n]
    m = input('input number : ')
    y[nn] = m
    print y
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Oh Sorry the question is i can not to update input operation values 5 cannot update to 11 when i sum new values 6

Comment: Shortened problem description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program does have its problems.  First of all, a dictionary is overkill for your menu of choices.  Since you never change it, you can simply hard-code the choices and print the list each time.

Your **y** dictionary is a collection of running sums -- accumulations -- for the five items.  You never got a sum because your code only replaces an existing value with a new one.  I've added code to check whether the item is already in **y**; if so, the new code adds the new value to the old.

```
y = {}
x = " abcde"
while True:
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        print i, ':', x[i]
    n = input('choose the number of the key you want to update:')
    key_num = x[n]
    print 'your choice is ',x[n]
    m = input('input update quantity : ')
    if key_num in y:
        y[key_num] += m
    else:
        y[key_num] = m
    print y
```

Output:

```
$ python2.7 so.py
1 : a
2 : b
3 : c
4 : d
5 : e
choose the number of the key you want to update:4
your choice is  d
input update quantity : 5
{'d': 5}
1 : a
2 : b
3 : c
4 : d
5 : e
choose the number of the key you want to update:1
your choice is  a
input update quantity : 5
{'a': 5, 'd': 5}
1 : a
2 : b
3 : c
4 : d
5 : e
choose the number of the key you want to update:4
your choice is  d
input update quantity : 6
{'a': 5, 'd': 11}
1 : a
2 : b
3 : c
4 : d
5 : e
choose the number of the key you want to update:
-- I interrupted the program --
```

Does this get you moving to the next stage?